# running access query and copying the results into excel

Tags: vba, excel, ms-access

I am fairly new at VBA, I apologize if this question is not up to the standards.

I am trying to run the Access query and copy the results to the Excel worksheet.

So far I have managed to open Access DB and run the query, but I can not find anything on how to copy the results into excel, at least I am not able to find a working solution.

Can someone please direct me in the right direction please.

Thank you.

So far I came up with the following code.

```
Sub AccessTest1()

    Dim A As Object
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Set A = CreateObject("Access.Application")

    A.Visible = True
    A.OpenCurrentDatabase ("acess database path")
    A.DoCmd.OpenQuery ("query")
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True


End Sub
```

Comment: You need to refer to the `RecordSet` object. Then make a loop - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff197799.aspx

Comment: Why use VBA? you can access that query directly from Data, Get External Data

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at the [CopyFromRecordset](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-copyfromrecordset-method-excel) method.

> Copies the contents of an ADO or DAO Recordset object onto a
>   worksheet, beginning at the upper-left corner of the specified range.

```
'...
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

Dim rs As Object
Set rs = A.CurrentDb().QueryDefs("QueryName").OpenRecordset()

If Not rs.EOF Then
    ws.Range("A1").CopyFromRecordset rs
End If

rs.Close
```

Comment: thank you @Kostas K. for your reply, I have tried .OpenRecordset() method and it keeps throwing me an error :/

I have came across .OpenRecordset() before but I couldn't get it to work, even with a code as simple as you provided

Comment: It would certainly help to add the full error message to your question @Mr.Riply

Comment: I apologize, I got it to work, thank you very much for your help